# 110 block vs UR IDC for telephone line connections

Tags: electrical, low-voltage, telephone

I have a landline telephone line that branches out to 5 telephone outlets. Would it be better to use 110 block or a UR IDC (red scotchlock) connector for the connections/splices? Would water/moisture be a concern for the 110 block? I have attached an image of both connectors.

[image: 110 block and red idc connector]

Comment: The answer depends on several factors not mentioned. What is the environment? How often will changes be made? Etc.

Comment: It will be in my basement, changes will never be made

Comment: What about a [66 block](https://amzn.to/3Y2zGYP)? That's traditionally how you patched a bunch of phones together.

Answer (score 1):

In an environment like a basement, both are totally fine, as is a 66 block. Scotchlocks are less flexible but often cheaper and don't need a specialized tool to install. I like 110 blocks because connecting multiple jacks to a single line is very  visible and the tool is easier to use than the 66 tool. For a setup where changes will never be made, Scotchlocks are totally reasonable, especially if it's just a few jacks.